# Strategies for synchronizing indexedDB on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I wrote a Windows 8 / JavaScript application that uses indexeddb as its storage mechanism based on this guidance by MS (I have large amount of data).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781225.aspx

I would like now to provide a way for users to synchronize across their Win 8 devices.

What options are available to synchronize the indexeddb data across devices?

Comment: Do you want to synchronize large amounts of data across Win8 devices?

Comment: @JPAlioto Yes, It is a large number of records, not necessarily lot of MBs stored in IndexedDb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IndexedDB is designed for client-side storage scenarios.  The API is not designed to handle synchronization to a server-side database.  You are going to have to write some code to do that.  There are a few of ways that you can accomplish the task; from least fidelity least work to most fidelity most work:

- Use the [built in Windows 8 app data roaming capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464917.aspx#roaming_app_data).  The
  pros of this approach are that it is built in functionality.  The
  cons are that there are limits to how much data you can synchronize
  across devices.  See [Roaming Your App Data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/07/17/roaming-your-app-data.aspx) for a further
  discussion.
- You can use a back-end service that already exists like [Skydrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521)
  or [Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/).  The pros here are that the
  server-side work is easier and the APIs already exist.  The con (I
  guess) is that there may be less fidelity than the last option
  (below).
- You can build your own back end that handles the sync.  The pros here
  are that this option offers you the most fidelity and control of how
  the system works.  The con is pretty obvious -- this is the most
  work.

Which option you choose depends on your particular needs.

Comment: Thanks! I understand IndexedDB is client storage, but I was hoping for a more built in solution / guidance from MS on how to synchronize IndexedDB with other devices similar to the data roaming capabilities. I don't want to move data to backend, app is meant to be used offline most of the time. I think this scenario is lacking considering the Win8 emphasis on synched devices and guidance use of IndexedDB for storage.  Thanks again for the help though!